# Files: Unable to mount server (SSH)

Tags: pantheon-files

I'd like to use Pantheon to connect to a remote server via `ssh`. I verified that the credentials correct - I can connect via `ssh` in the terminal.

It appears to connect, but then says

```
Unable to Mount Folder. Could not connect to the server for this folder.
```

No matter which folder I choose, `/`, `~`, or `/home/myuser` (I have read access to `/`).

Comment: What protocol are you using? Samba?

Comment: @wolf I'm selecting ssh in the option, as in sftp. (Did that answer the question?)

Comment: But trying `smb` in the url bar leads to the same problem.

Comment: I also had the same issues with the Files app. I installed nautilus and was easily able to access my personal network shares. I know it is not a 'fix' to install a different app, but thought it might help for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

There are two open bugs re: "unable to mount folder" and reading your `ssh` config:

- [SFTP and SMB can only access first time](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1596648)
- [Can't mount ssh/sftp/afp sharing [$100]](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-files/+bug/1615816)

Please subscribe there so as to help the devs diagnose the issue and test the proper fix.